# How to use pv to show progress of openssl encryption / decryption?

Tags: encryption, openssl, pv

I need to encrypt and be able to decrypt files with `openssl`, currently I do this simply with:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in "$input_filename" -out "$output_filename"
```

and the decryption with:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in "$input_filename" -out "$output_filename"
```

---

But with large files, I would like to see progress.

I tried different variations of the following (decryption):

```
pv "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt | pv > "$output_filename"
```

But this fails to ask me for a password. I am unsure as to how to go about it?

**EDIT1:**

I found this `tar` over `openssl`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24704457/1997354

While it could be extremely helpful, I don't get it much.

**EDIT2:**

Regarding the named pipe:

It almost works. Except for the *blinking* progress, which I can't show you obviously and the final result looking like this:

```
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
1.25GiB 0:00:16 [75.9MiB/s] [==============================================================================================================================================================================================>] 100%            
1.25GiB 0:00:10 [ 126MiB/s] [                                             <=>                                                                                                                                                                ]
```

Comment: This isn’t an answer since your question specifically asks for `pv`, but you could use [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) to track `openssl`’s progress.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. Very cool program!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in "$input_filename" | pv -W >> "$output_filename"
```

From [the Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> **-W, --wait**:
>
> Wait until the first byte has been transferred before showing any progress information or calculating any ETAs. Useful if the program you are piping to or from requires extra information before it starts, eg piping data into gpg(1) or mcrypt(1) which require a passphrase before data can be processed.

which is exactly your case. If you need to see the progress bar, for the reason clearly explained by *Weijun Zhou* in a comment below, you can reverse the order of the commands in the pipe:

```
pv -W "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out "$output_filename"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-bash) here.

```
$ mkfifo mypipe
$ pv < mypipe > "$output_filename"|(pv "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out mypipe)
```

The output of the two `pv` commands will show alternately at the bottom of your tty window. Not sure whether it is what you really need, though. If you only need the output of the `pv` in `pv "$input_filename"`, modify the above command accordingly.

**Edit**

After obtaining more information from the OP, I am now sure that

```
pv "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out "$output_filename"
```

is enough to address OP's **real** needs.